# Pandas group by cumsum length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum, index-error

As most of these help questions begin, I'm new to Python and Pandas. I've been learning by doing, especially when I have a particular task to complete. I have searched the help pages and could not find an answer that addressed by specific problem and I could not devise a solution based on answers to similar problems.

I have a data set with 50K+ entries. The general format is:

```
    code  value
0    101    0.0
1    102    0.0
2    103   23.2
3    104   10.3
4    105    0.2
5    106    0.0
6    107   22.6
7    108    0.0
8    109    0.0
9    110    2.2
10   111    3.8
11   112    0.0
```

My first task was to segregate consecutive non-zero values. Through trial and error, I managed to condense my script to one line that accomplished this.

```
df[df['value'] != 0].groupby((df['value'] == 0).cumsum())
for grp, val in df[df['value'] != 0].groupby((df['value'] == 0).cumsum()):
    print(f'[group {grp}]')
    print(val)
```

The output is:

```
[group 2]
   code  value
2   103   23.2
3   104   10.3
4   105    0.2
[group 3]
   code  value
6   107   22.6
[group 5]
    code  value
9    110    2.2
10   111    3.8
```

I have other manipulations and calculations to do on this data set and I think the easiest way to access these data would be to transform the groupby object into a column (if that is even the correct terminology?), like so:

```
   code  value  group
0   103   23.2      2
1   104   10.3      2
2   105    0.2      2
3   107   22.6      3
4   110    2.2      5
5   111    3.8      5
```

Obviously, I get a "Length of values does not match length of index" error. I searched the help pages and it seemed that I needed to do some type of reset_index method. I tried various syntax structures and many other coding solutions suggested in other threads the past day and a half without success. I finally decided to give up and ask for help when I returned from a short break and found my cat rolling on the keyboard, adding and deleting gobs of gibberish to the script snippets I had been testing.

If someone would be kind enough to help me with this script--to get the groupby object into a column, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: why not just drop all the rows of double 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the groups then drop the zero rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112],
 'value': [0.0, 0.0, 23.2, 10.3, 0.2, 0.0, 22.6, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2, 3.8, 0.0]})

df['group'] = df.value.eq(0).cumsum()
df = df.loc[df.value.ne(0)]
```

Output

```
    code  value  group
2    103   23.2      2
3    104   10.3      2
4    105    0.2      2
6    107   22.6      3
9    110    2.2      5
10   111    3.8      5
```

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect--and elegant compared to the script I had written.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Actually I did ✔ and up vote the answer, but I received a notice saying something to the effect that as a new user I didn't have enough presence on SO to do this, so I wrote a thank you instead.